# jQuery post from external js file in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery

I have to call a method which contains a `jquery.post` function and it's located in an external JavaScript file. I have tried as follows:

```
 jQuery.post('<%=Url.Action("SetFormSession","Home")%>')
```

but it's not converting the server's tag string to real a URL

> ("/Home/SetFormSession.aspx")

Comment: Define "external js file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%=Url.Action("SetFormSession","Home")%>` will not work in external js file.

instead declare a variable in view. In script section as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var actionUrl = '<%=Url.Action("SetFormSession","Home")%>';
</script>
```

And use `actionUrl` in external file.